# How to handle errors in update action (using Twitter gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, twitter

I'm making a simple Rails app with the Twitter gem. The app prompts users to select values from a form select and those get put into a tweet. Because the user is selecting values from a form select, and because there are default values, there is a high probability that the user (clicking impatiently on the "post to twitter" button) will try to create duplicate tweets, which is forbidden by Twitter

> Twitter::Error::Forbidden in SessionsController#update
>
> Status is a duplicate.

Thus, this noob is trying to create his first error handler

```
   def update
     @twit = "@TwitterUser  #{params[:wants]} to go to  #{params[:place]} "

     begin
       client.update(@twit)
       redirect_to show_path, :notice => "' ' + #{params[:wants] + ' ' + params[:place]    has been tweeted}"

     rescue Exception
       redirect_to show_path, :notice => "Hey Loser, Twitter says you cannot post same twice"
     end 
   end
```

**Problem,** sometimes it's showing the error message when I don't post the same message twice in a row. I'm wondering if the error message is sticking somehow, or have I written the action in such a way that it might do this?

**Extra** this is the first time i've tried to include an error message, i have no idea if i'm doing it right or wrong or it could be done better. if you have any tips about where this code might go...much appreciated. for example, I have several forms/actions that are possibly going to raise the same error so is there a DRY technique i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that some other type of error is being thrown, not that it's 'sticking'. You would need to trace your error log (or use a debugger) to see what Exception is being thrown (and rescued). You can also use multiple rescue cases to test for various exceptions, like so:

```
begin
   client.update(@twit)
   redirect_to show_path, :notice => "' ' + #{params[:wants] + ' ' + params[:place]    has been tweeted}"
 rescue Twitter::Error
   redirect_to show_path, :notice => "Hey Loser, Twitter says you cannot post same twice"
 rescue Exception
   puts "some other error happened!"
 end
```

Another option to for handling errors is to make assignments, evaluate, and raise any exceptions like so:

```
begin
   response = client.update(@twit)
   if !response
      raise "something went wrong!"
   else
       redirect_to show_path, :notice => "' ' + #{params[:wants] + ' ' + params[:place]    has been tweeted}"
   end

 rescue Exception
   redirect_to show_path, :notice => "Hey Loser, Twitter says you cannot post same twice"
 end
```

Comment: so in the second example, does the user get two error messages "something went wrong" and then a further explanation "Hey Loser...", or are they for separate errors?

Comment: In the second example you would only get one exception, if client.update(@twit) would throw a Twitter::Error you would be returned from the begin block and put into the rescue block (thus never executing the if/else)...